# Python: Passing conditional parameters by name

Tags: python

I have a bunch of functions, some of them require a `bar` parameter, some of them require a `foo` parameter, some of them require neither, and some require both.

I am hoping to call all of these functions from the same location, as the function is referenced from a variable.

The possible solutions I have found is:

1. function(bar = "some_value", foo = "other value")
2. Using inspect and then detecting which arguments need to be passed in

I don't believe #1 will work, but I know that #2 will.  Is there a native (not using a library) way for me to do this?

As an example:

```
functions = [lambda foo: foo.do_something(),
             lambda bar: bar.do_something_else(),
             lambda foo, bar: foo.something_with_bar(bar),
             lambda: do_another_task()
]
for function in functions:
    //call goes here
```

Note:  I actually have many, many functions that I want to call with these parameters, and they aren't all stored nicely in an array.  I would prefer if I could do it without changing the functions themselves.

Comment: @Downvoter/close voter:  What additional information do you need, exactly?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you need to add your actual code so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: The brute force/naive approach would probably be to call the passed function in a series of try/except blocks with the different permutations until one succeeded.  With only 4 possibilities, that might even be a better solution than using inspect.  Another important point though here is whether this function is itself an argument, or being registered to some sort of handler.  If it is a registry of some sort, it may well be worth doing some preprocessing to categorize the function the first time you see it, then call it intelligently thereafter.

Comment: Wait, so `foo` and `bar` might not only be _arguments_ to the function, but also _instances_ from which you are referencing the function?  That's a more complicated scenario...

Comment: Your example is almost there, just give the lambdas a uniform signature.

Comment: @jhermann You're right, but this seems more and more like an XY problem...

Comment: @jhermann what do you mean?  have the same variables pass into both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off storing a *lambda expression* in a variable, instead of the underlying function, and binding your arguments in the lambda. Something like:

```
foo = 'foo'
bar = 'bar'
if funcname == 'a':
  func = a  # a takes no args
elif funcname == 'b':
  func = lambda: bb(bar=bar)  # bb takes bar
elif funcname == 'c':
  func = lambda: ccc(foo=foo)  # ccc takes foo
# call it, uniformly
func()
```

A similar approach would be to "de-bind":

```
if funcname == 'a':
  func = lambda foo, bar: a()  # don't pass foo and bar
elif funcname == 'b':
  func = lambda foo, bar: bb(bar=bar)  # don't pass foo
elif funcname == 'c':
  func = lambda foo, bar: ccc(foo=foo)  # don't pass bar
# call it, uniformly
func(foo, bar)
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to refactor your code to make it more elegant and object-oriented, define an interface and facade implementations:

```
class FooBarInterface(object):
    def f(self, foo, bar):
        raise NotImplementedError
class A(FooBarInterface):
    def f(self, foo, bar):
        return a()
class B(FooBarInterface):
    def f(self, foo, bar):
        return bb(bar=bar)
class C(FooBarInterface):
    def f(self, foo, bar):
        return ccc(foo=foo)

if funcname == 'a':
  obj = A()
elif funcname == 'b':
  obj = B()
elif funcname == 'c':
  obj = C()
# call it, uniformly
obj.f()
```

---

And please don't use introspection. It would make your code way more complicated than need be.

Comment: My problem is that I have many functions I want to call this way, and I don't really want to change all of the functions to fit the call.

Comment: Well, this is the most comprehensive answer, and it tells me that there really isn't a way to do what I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it natively unless you can edit the functions themselves, if you have you could have

```
def func_a(**kwargs):
    foo = kwargs['foo']
    # or even:
    foo = kwargs.get('foo', None) # in case foo wasn't passed the the function
    ...

def func_b(**kwargs):
    bar = kwargs.get('bar', None)
    ...
```

With the functions setup that way you can pass any key word arguments you like.